# i18n Attaching variable in the middle of a string

Tags: internationalization, apostrophe-cms

I have this phrase :

`{{ __("counter.description:This promotion is limited to X participants") }}`

I want to change the X by a variable

My key is `counter.description`

And I tried to do this in my singular value : `This promotion is limited to {{totalParticipation}} participants`

But it's not working.

Di you have any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to get the result you are looking for:

1. Insert the phrase in your page template this way. Note that the key name has no periods in it. Also note that the interpolated variable is passed as part of an object.

```
{{ __t('promotionDescription', { n: 5 }) }}
```

2. Add the phrase to an `i18n/en.json` file inside **any module** of your Apostrophe project. **Important:** this must be in a subdirectory called `i18n` **inside** your module. Otherwise it will not be found and loaded for you.

```
{
  "promotionDescription": "This promotion is limited to {{ n }} participants"
}
```

3. When you're ready to actually translate, copy `en.json` to `fr.json`, `es.json`, etc. (or whatever your configured locales are) in the same directory and translate the contents, keeping the key names and interpolated variable names the same, just translate the text.
4. Don't forget to actually configure those same locales in the `@apostrophecms/i18n` module, otherwise they won't be picked up.

See documentation links below:

https://docs.apostrophecms.org/guide/localization/static.html
https://docs.apostrophecms.org/guide/localization/overview.html#configuring-locales